# Problem with declaring 2D vector in Arduino

Tags: c++

I have included the STL library in Arduino and i can run a program with 1D vector.
But i am getting error while declaring a 2D vector.

```
#include <StandardCplusplus.h>
#include <serstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;

vector <vector<int> > grid;
vector<int> col(5,3);
grid.push_back(col);

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(grid[[0][i]);
  }
}
```

And the error is

```
'grid' does not name a type.
```

Do i need to add another header file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from

```
 grid.push_back(col);
```

You cannot have this line at the top-most level outside a function / main. Move it inside `setup` or `loop`.